# In a wikidata SPARQL query how to address a file?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

**How to address a commons Media File?**

In wikidata want to find all objects, which have a commons media file attached through a specific property with a SPARQL query.

**Example:**

```
SELECT ?item
{
    # get all objects which have this file as a LocatorMap
    ?item wdt:P242 commons:LocationPeru.svg
}
```

This does not work and neither do all variants like `wd:commons:LocationPeru.svg`, `p:P242 [ps:P242 psv:commons:LocationCuba.svg]` or everything else I tried. I also tried a `FILTER` with the label but `rdfs:label ?label` did not work for me on the fileobject.

So, how is the correct syntax?

Thanks.

*Actually, I want to filter out specific ones from a more complex query with `MINUS`, but reduced my problem to this.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the image's full URL:

```
SELECT ?item
{
  ?item wdt:P242 <http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/LocationPeru.svg>
}
```

Actually, from the above query it seems that no item indicates `LocationPeru.svg` as locator map. This is because in [Q419#P242](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q419#P242) there is an higher-ranked locator map.

For ignoring the statements' ranking, you can use:

```
SELECT ?item
{
  ?item p:P242 [ ps:P242 <http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/LocationPeru.svg> ]
}
```

For filtering only the *normal* rank, you can use:

```
SELECT ?item
{
  ?item p:P242 [
      ps:P242 <http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/LocationPeru.svg> ;
      wikibase:rank wikibase:NormalRank
    ]
}
```